# zebra send pdf to the printer with python 2.7

Tags: python, printing, python-2.x, zebra-printers

I m looking for a way to send a pdf (or a byteArray) content to my zebra printer (zq630).

I tried to put direct pdf firmware on the printer and do that :

```
 mysocket.connect((host, 9100))
        f = open(savepath + ".pdf", "rb")
        l = f.read(1024)
        while l :
            _logger.error(l)
            mysocket.send(bytes(l))
            l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
        mysocket.close()
```

But it "print" blank pages until the end of the roll.. :(

I also try to convert my pdf to an image and then send it by zpl to the printer like this :

```
        with Image(filename=savepath + ".pdf[0]") as img:
            img.save(filename=savepath + ".png")

        fd_img = open(savepath + ".png", 'r')
        img = ImagePillow.open(fd_img)
        #img = resizeimage.resize_contain(img, [100, 150])
        img.save(savepath + ".png", dpi=[203,203])
        fd_img.close()
        # convert png to zpl
        # im = pilloImg.open(savepath+".png")

        convert = ZPLConvert(savepath + ".png")
        # convert.set_compress_hex(True)
        result = convert.convert(None, True)
        f = open(savepath + ".zpl", "wb")
        f.write(result)
        f.close()
        mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        mysocket.connect((host, 9100))
        f = open(savepath + ".pdf", "rb")
        l = f.read(1024)
        while l :
            _logger.error(l)
            mysocket.send(bytes(l))
            l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
        mysocket.close()
```

But with this method, when i save the png , the image is ok but when i print it , it s really small and the image is already really degraded so i don t think it s the good way to do that isn  t it?

Could you help please? Do you have any example wity python 2.7?

is it a bad configuration on my printer or it s in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the simulation print in http://labelary.com/viewer.html, add image and compare with your codes output. Because sometimes your output isnt the ideal.
Like that:

```
^XA

^FO50,50^GFA,49770,49770,79,,::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::gO03,gO01C,gO01E,gP0F8,gO08FC,gO087E,gO083F,gL0200C3F8,gL0300C1FC,gL0300C1FF,gL0380C0FFCI0LFC,gL0780E0IFC03LFC,gL07C0E07IFC03KF8,gL07C0E07IFE003JF,gL03C0E03IFEI0JF8,gL03E0F03F3FFI07JF8,gL03E0F01C0FFI07NFC,gL03E07J03F8007NF8,gL03F07J01F8007NF,gL03F078J0F8007NF,gL01F078J07C007FE03KF,gL01F878J03C007FE00LF,gL01F838J01C007FE00MFC,gL01F83CJ01C00FFE00NF8,gM0FC3CK0C00FFE01NFC,gM0FC1CK0600FFC01NFC,gM0FC1CN0FFC03FE7KFC,gM07E1EN0FFC03FC3LFC,gM07E0EN0FFC07FC1MFC,gM07E0EN0FFC07F801MFC,gM03F06N0FFC07F8007MF,gM03F02N0FFC0FF800NF,gM01F8N01FFC0FFI0NF,gM01F8N01FF81FF001MFE,gM01FCN01FF81FF003FC7JFE,gN0FCN01FF81FE007FC3KF,gN0FEN01FF83FE007F81KFC,gN07EN01FF83FE00FF00LF,gN07EN03FF83FC00FF003KFE,gN03EN03FF83FC01FE001LFC,gN03CN03FF07F803FE001FE7JF8,gN01CN03FF07F803FC003FC1KF,gN018N07FF07F807FC007FC07JFE,gP078L07FF07F007F800FF807KF8,gP0F8CK07FF0FF00FF800FF007JFE,gO01F8CK07FE0FF00FF001FE00KFE,gO03F0CK0FFE0FF00FF003FC01LF,gO07F0CK0FFE1FF01FF007FC03LFC,gO0FF0CJ01FFE1FE01FE00FF807MF8,gN01FE0CJ01FFE1FE03FE01FF00NFE,gN01FE0EJ03FFC1FE03FE01FF00OF8,gN03FC0EJ03EFC3FC07FC03FE01FFC7KFE,gN07FC0EJ07C7C3FC07FC07FC03FF80LF8,gN0FF81EJ0F87C3FC07FC0FFC07FF800KF8,gN0FF81EJ0E0FC3FC0FF80FF80IFI0KF,gM01FF01EL0F87FC0FF81FF01FFEI0JFC,gM03FE01CL0F87F80FF81FE01FFC003JFC,gM03FE03CL0F87F81FF03FE03FF8007JFE,gM07FC03C6J01F87F81FF07FC07FF800LF,gM0FF803C4J01F07F81FF07F80IF001IF3FFE,gM0FF807C4J01F0FF81FE0FF80FFE003FFE1IF8,gL01FF0078CJ01F0FF03FE0FF01FFE003FFC0IFE,gL01FE00F884I01F0FF03FE1FE03FFC007FF80JFC,gL03FE00F184I03F0FF03FE1FE03FF800IF00JFE,gL07FC01E18CI03E0FF07FC1FC07FF801FFE01KF,gL07F803E19CI03E0FF07FC3FC0IF003FFC03KF,gL0FF0078318I03E0FE07FC3F80FFE007FFC07JF8,gK01FF00E0338I03E1FE07F83F01FFE00IF80KF8,gK01FEJ07381003E1FE07F87F01FFC01IF01KF8,gK03FCJ07381003E1FE0FF87E03FFC01FFE03KFE,gK03F8J07381007C1FE0FF87E03FF803FFE07FFC7FFC,gK07F8J0E781007C1FC0FF87C07FF007FFC0IF83IF8,gK0FFK0E781007C1FC0FF87C0IF00IF80IF00JF,gK0FE07E00E781007C1FC0FF0780FFE00IF81FFE00JFC,gJ01FC1FF81C781807C1FC1FF0781FFE01IF03FFE00KF8,gJ01F83FF81C781807C1FC1FF0701FFC03FFE07FFC01KF8,gJ03F87FF81C78180781FC1FF0703FFC03FFE0IF803KF8,gJ07F0IF83C78180783F81FF0603FF807FFC0IF003JF,gJ07E0IF03878180F83F81FF0607FF80IF81FFE007IFC,gJ0FC1IF07878180F83F83FE0407FF00IF03FFE00FFBFC,gI01F80FFC078781C0F83F83FEI07FF01IF03FFC00FF1FC,gI01F8K070781C0F83F83FEI0FFE03FFE07FF801FE0FF,gI03FL0F0781C0F83F83FEI0FFE03FFE0IF803FE07F8,gI03EL0F0781C0F83F03FE001FFC07FFC0IF003FC03FC,gI07CK01E0781C0F83F03FE001FFC07FF81IF007FC03FF,gI078K03E0781E0F03F07FE001FF80IF81FFE00FF803FF8,gI0FL07C0381E0F03F07FC003FF80IF03FFC00FF807FFE,gH01EL0FC03C1E0F03F07FC003FF01IF03FFC01FF00IFE,gH01E07FF07F803C0E0F03F07FC007FF01FFE07FF801FF00FFE,gH03C0LF003C0E0F03F07FC007FE03FFE07FF803FE01FFE,gH0381LF003C0E0F03E07FC007FE03FFC0IF003FE03F9E,gH07K07F8003C0F0F03E07FC00FFC07FFC0IF007FE03F1F,gH06P03C0F0F03E07FC00FFC07FF81FFE007FC07F0F8,gH0CP01C0F0F03E0FFC01FFC0IF81FFE00FFC07E078,gG018P01E0F0F03E0FF801FF80IF03FFC00FF80FE03C,gG018P01E0F0F03E0FF801FF80IF03FFC01FF80FC01E,gG03Q01E0F0F03E0FF803FF01FFE07FF801FF80FC00F,gG02K0JF801E078F03E0FF803FF01FFE07FF803FF01FC0078,gJ03LF801E078703C0FF803FF03FFC0IF003FF01F80078,gI0NFC01E078703C0FF807FE03FFC0IF003FF03F8001C,gI03MFE00E078703C0FF807FE07FFC0IF007FE03FJ0E,gJ01JF03E00F078703C0FF807FC07FF81FFE007FE07FJ06,gP01F00F078703C0FF807FC07FF81FFE00FFE07FJ03,gQ0F00F07C703C0FF00FFC0IF81FFE00FFE07EJ038,gQ0F80F07C303C1FF00FF80IF03FFC00FFC0FEJ03E,gQ0780F03C303C1FF00FF80IF03FFC01FFC0FEJ03F8,W078004O0780F03C303C1FF01FF01IF03FFC01FFC0FEJ07FC,V01FE007IFL07C0F03C30381FF01FF01FFE07FF803FFC1FCJ07FCh01JF8,V03FE001KFJ07C0F83C10381FF01FF01FFE07FF803FF81FCJ07FCgW01LFE,V07FFJ0KFI07C0783E10381FF01FE03FFC07FF803FF81FC0400FFCgV0NF8,V07FF8J03IFC007C0783E10381FF03FE03FFC0IF007FF83F80C00FFCgU03NF,V0IF8L07FE003E0783E10381FE03FE03FFC0IF007FF83F80C00FF8gU07MFC,U01IFCM0FE003E0783E08381FE03FC07FF80IF007FF03F80800FF8I01CgK0FC001NF,U01IFCM07F003E0783E00381FE03FC07FF81FFE00IF03F81801FF8I03F8gG01IFI03MFCO03F8,U03IFCM03F003E0783E00383FE07FC07FF81FFE00IF07F01801FF8I03FCY01JFEI0NFO0IFE,U03IFCM01F803E0783F00183FE07F80IF01FFE00IF07F01801FFJ03FCW01LF8003MFEM01KFC,U07IFE00FK0F803E0783F00183FE07F80IF01FFC01IF07F03801FFJ03FC007CQ07MFEI0NF8L01MF,U07IFE001EJ0FC01E0783F00103FE07F80IF03FFC01FFE07F03803FFJ03FC007FCO0OF8001MFEL01NFC,U07IFEI03CI07C01E0F83F00103FC0FF00IF03FFC01FFE0FE03803FE01807FC00FFC00FDFI01NFEI03MF8L07OF,U0JFEI01F8007C01E0F83F00103FC0FF01FFE03FFC03FFE0FE07803FE01807FC00FFC01IFI01NF8I0MFEL03PF8,U0JFEJ07C003E01E0F83F00103FC0FF01FFE07FF803FFE0FE07803FE03807FC00FFC00IFI03MFEI03MF8K01QFE,U0JFEJ03F003E01C0F83F00103FC0FE01FFE07FF803FFE0FE07807FC03C07FC00FFC00IFI03MF8I07LFEL0SF8,U0KFK0F803E00C0F83F00303FC0FE03FFE07FF803FFC0FE0F807FC07C07FC00FFC00IFI07MFI01MF8K03SFC,T01KFK07C01E00C0F83F00303F81FE03FFC07FF807FFC1FC0F807FC07C07F800FFC00IFI07LFCI03LFEK01SF,T01KFK07E01F0081F83F80307F81FC03FFC0IF007FFC1FC0F007F807C0FF800FFC00IFI0MFJ0MFCK07QF,T01KF00C003F01FI01F83F00307F81FC03FFC0IF007FFC1FC0F00FF80FC0FF800FFC00IFI0LFEI01MFK01PFE,T01KF807001F81FI01F83F00207F81FC03FFC0IF00IF81FC0F00FF80FC0FF800FFC00IF001LF8I07LFCK07OFC,T01KF803E00F81FI03F83C00207F83FC07FFC0IF00IF81FC1F00FF81FC0FF800FFC00IF001KFEJ0MFK01OFC,T01KFC01F80FC1FI03FK0207F83F807FF81IF00IF83FC1F00FF01FC0FF800FFC007FF003KFCI01LFEK07NFE,T01KFE01FC07C0FI03FK0207F03F807FF81FFE00IF83F81F01FF03FC0FF800FFE007FF003KFJ07LF8J01OF,T01LF00FF07E0FI07FK0607F03F807FF81FFE01IF83F81F01FF03FC0FF800FFE007FF007JFEJ0LFEK07NF8,T01LF807F83E0FI078K060FF07F00IF81FFE01IF03F83F01FF03FC1FF800FFE007FF007JFCI03LFCK0NFE,T01LFC07F83E0FI06L060FF07F00IF01FFE01IF07F83F01FE07FC1FF800FFE007FF80KFJ07LFK03NF,T01LFC03FC3E1FR0FF07F00IF03FFC03IF07F83F03FE07F81FF800FFE007FF80JFEJ0LFEK0NFC,U0LFE03FC3E0FR0FE07F00IF03FFC03IF07F83F03FE07F81FF800FFE007FF81JFCI03LF8J01NF,U0MF01FC3E0FQ01FE07E00IF03FFC03FFE07F83E03FE07F81FF800FFE007FF81JFJ07LFK07MF8,U0MF81FC3E1FQ01FE07E00IF03FFC07FFE07F03E03FE0FF81FFC00FFE007FF83IFEJ0LFCK0MFE,U0MFC0FC3E1EQ01FC0FE01FFE03FFC07FFE0FF03E07FC0FF81FFC00FFE007FF83IFCI01LF8J03MF8,U0MFC0FC3E18Q03FC0FC01FFE07FF807FFE0FF07E07FC0FF81FFC00FFE007FF87IF8I07KFEK07MF,U07LFC0FC3CS03FC0FC01FFE07FF807FFC0FF07E07FC0FF01FFC00IF007FFCJFJ0LFCJ01MFCU0IFC,U07LFE0F83CS01F80FC01FFE07FF80IFC0FF07E07FC1FF01FFC00IF007LFEI01LF8J03MFS01KFE,U07LFE07878T0F80FC01FFE07FF80IFC1FF07E07F81FF01FFC00IF007LFCI03KFEK0MFER0MFE,U03LFE078V0700F801FFC0IF80IFC1FF07E0FF81FF01FFC00IF007LF8I0LFCJ01MF8P01OF,U03MF07W0701F803FFC0IF01IFC1FE07E0FF81FF01FFC00IF007LFI01LF8J07MFP01PF8,U01MF0EW0301F803FFC0IF01IF81FE07E0FF83FE01FFC00IF007KFEI03KFEK0MFCP0QFC,U01MFgG01F803FF80IF01IF81FE0FC0FF83FE03FFC00IF003KFCI07KFCJ01MF8O07QFC,V0MFgG01F003FF80IF01IF83FE0FC0FF03FE01FFC00IF007KF8I0LF8J03LFEO03RFE,V0MFgG01F003FF81IF03IF83FE0FC0FF03FE01FFC00IF003KFI01LFK07LFCN01TF,V07KFEgG01F003FF01FFE03IF83FE0FC1FF03FC01FFC007FF803JFEI03KFEJ01MF8N0UF,V07KFEgG01F003FF01FFE03IF03FC0FC1FF03FC01FFE007FF803JFEI07KF8J03LFEN07UF8,V03KFEgG01E003FF01FFE03IF03FC0FC1FF03FC01FFE007FF803JFCI0LFK07LFCM01VF8,V01KFEgG03E007FE03FFC07IF07FC0FC1FF07FC01FFE007FF803JF8001KFEK0MF8M07VF8,W0KFEgG03E007FE03FFC07IF07FC1FC1FF07FC01FFE007FF803JFI03KFCJ01MFM01TFE,W03JFCgG03E007FE03FFC07FFE07FC1FC1FE07F801FFE007FF803JFI07KF8J03LFCM03SF,Y01FF8gG03E007FC07FFC0IFE07F81F81FE07F801FFE007FF803IFEI0LFK0MF8M0RFC,g03FgH03C007FC07FF80IFE07F81F81FE07F801FFE007FF803IFC001KFEJ01MFM03QF8,hJ01C007F807FF80IFE07F81F83FE07F801FFE007FFC03IF8003KFCJ03LFEM07PFC,hJ01C007F00IF81IFC0FF81F83FE07F801FFE007FFC03IF8007KF8J07LFCL01PFC,hK0C007F00IF01IFC0FF81F83FE07F001IF003FFC03IFI0LFK0MF8L03OFE,hN0FE01IF01IFC0FF81F83FE07F001IF003FFC01IF001KFEJ01MFM07OF,hN0FC01IF01IF80FF03F83FE07F001IF003FFC01FFE001KFCJ03LFEL01OF8,hN0F801FFE03IF80FF03F83FC07F001IF003FFC01FFC003KF8J07LFCL03NFC,hN0F003FFE03IF81FF03F03FC07F001IF003FFC01FFC007KFK07LF8L07NF,hN0C003FFC07IF81FF03F03FC07F001IF003FFC01FF800LFK0MFM0NF8,hQ07FFC07IF01FF03F03FC07F001IF003FFE01FF800KFEJ01LFEL01MFET06,hQ07FFC07IF01FE03F03FC07F001IF803FFE00FF001KFCJ03LFCL03MF8T0E,hQ0IF807IF03FE03F03FC07FI0IF801FFE00FF003KF8J07LF8L07LFET01E,hQ0IF80IFE03FE07F03FC07FI0IF801FFE00FE003KFK0MF8L0MF8T01E,hP01IF00IFE03FE07F03FC07FI0IF801FFE00FC007JFEK0MFL01MFU03E,hP03IF01IFE03FE07E03FC07FI0IF801FFE007C00KFEJ01LFEL01LFCU07F,hP03FFE01IFC03FC07E03FC07FI0IF801FFE007800KFCJ03LFCL03LFU01FF,hP07FFE01IFC07FC07E03FC07FI0IFC01IF007801KF8J07LF8L07KFCU03FF,hP0IFC03IF807FC07E03FC07FI0IFC01IF007801KFK07LFM0LF8U07FF,hO01IF803IF807FC0FE03FC07FI07FFC00IF003003KFK0MFM0KFEV0IF,hO03IF803IF807F80FC03FC07FI07FFC00IF003003JFEJ01LFEL01KFCU03IF,hO07IF007IF00FF80FC03FC07FI07FFC00IFK03JFCJ03LFCL03KF8U0JF,hO0IFE007IF00FF80FC03FC03FI07FFC00IFK07JFCJ03LF8L03KFU01JF,hN03IFC00JF00FF80FC03FC03FI07FFE00IF8J07JF8J07LF8L07JFEU07JF,hN03IF800IFE01FF80FC03FC03F8007FFE00IF8J07JFK07LFM07JFCT01KF,hN03IF001IFE01FF01F803FC03F8003FFE007FF8J0KFK0LFEM0KFU07KF,hN01FFE001IFC01FF01F801FC03F8003FFE007FF8J0JFEJ01LFCM0KFU0LF,hO0FFC001IFC01FF01F801FC03F8003FFE007FF8J0JFEJ01LFCL01JFET03LF,hO0FF8003IF803FF01F801FC01F8003IF007FF8J0JFCJ01LF8L01JFCS01MF,hO07EI07IF803FE01F801FC01F8003IF007FF8J0JFCJ03LFM03JF8S07MF,hO03CI07IF003FE03F801FC01FC001IF007FF8J0JF8J03LFM03JFS03NF,hO03J0JF003FE03F001FE01FC001IF007FF8I01JF8J07KFEM07JFS0NFC,hT0IFE007FE03F001FE01FC001IF007FFCI01JFK07KFCM07IFER03NF8,hS01IFE007FC03FI0FE00FC001IF803FFCI01JFK07KFCM0JFCQ01OF,hS03IFC007FC03FI0FE00FEI0IF803FFCI01IFEK0LF8M0JFCQ07NFC,hS03IFC00FFC07EI0FE00FEI0IF803FFCI01IFEK0LF8L01JF8P01OF,hS07IF800FF807EI0FE00FEI0IF803FFCI01IFCK0LFM01JF8P0OFE01,hS0JFI0FF807EI0FE007FI0IF803FFCI01IFCJ01KFEM03JFP03OF801,hR01JF001FF807EI07F007FI07FFC03FFCI01IF8J01KFEM07JFO01OFE001,hR03IFE001FF00FCI07F007FI07FFC03FFCI01IF8J01KFCM07JFO07OF8001,hR07IFC001FF00FCI07F007F8007FFC01FFEI01IF8J01KFCM0JFEN03OFEI01,hR0JFC003FF00FCI03F003F8003FFC01FFEI01IF8J03KF8M0JFEN0PF8I03,hQ01JF8003FE00FCI03F003F8003FFC01FFEI01IF8J03KFM01JFEM03OFCJ03,hQ03JFI07FE01F8I03F803FC003FFE01FFEI01IFK03KFM03JFCM0PFK03,hQ03IFEI07FE01F8I01F801FC003FFE01FFEI01IFK03JFEM03JFCL03OFCK07,hQ01IFCI07FC01F80201F801FC001FFE01FFEI01IFK07JFEM07JF8L0OFEL07,hR0IF8I0FFC01F00201F801FE001FFE00FFEI01IFK07JFCM0KF8K03OF8L07,hR0IFJ0FF803F00200F800FE001FFE00FFEI01IFK07JFCL01KFL07NFCM0F,hR07FEI01FF803F00200FC00FE001IF00FFEI01IFK07JFCL03JFEK01OFN0F,hR07FCI01FF803E00200FC007FI0IF00IFI01IFK07JF8L03JFCK07NF8N0F,hR03F8I03FF007E006007C007FI0IF00IFI01IFK0KF8L07JFCK0NFEN01F,hR03FJ03FF007E006007C007FI0IF00IFI01IFK0KFM0KFK03NFO01F,hR01CJ07FE00FC00E003E003F800IF00IFI01IFK0KFL01KFK07MF8O01F,hX07FE00FC00E003E003F8007FF007FFI01IFK0JFEL03JFCK0MFEP03F,hX0FFC01F801E003E003F8007FF807FFI01IFK0JFEL07JF8J03MFQ03F8,hX0FFC01F801E001F001FC007FF807FFI01IFJ01JFEL0KFK07LFCQ07F8,hW01FF801F001E001F001FC003FF807FFI01IFJ01JFCK01JFEK0LFER07F8,hW01FF803F003CI0F001FC003FF807FF8001IFJ01JFCK03JFCJ01LF8R0FF8,hW03FF803E007CI07800FE003FF807FF8001IFJ01JF8K07JF8J03KFCS0FF8,hW07FF007E007CI07800FE003FF803FF8001IFJ01JF8K0KFK07KFS01FF8,hW07FE00FC00F8I03800FE001FF803FF8001IFJ01JFK01JFCK0KFCS01FF8,hW0FFE00FC00F80603C007F001FFC03FF8001IFJ01JFK03JF8K0JFET03FF8,hV01FFC01F801F00601C007F001FFC03FF8001IFJ03JFK07JFK01JF8S063FF8,hV03FFC01F803F00F00E003F001FFC03FF8001IFJ03IFEK0JFEK03IFET0E7FF8,hV03FF803F007E00F80E003FI0FFC03FF8001IFJ03IFEJ01JFCK03IF8S01C7FF8,hV07FF003E007E01F807003F800FFC01FF8001IFJ03IFEJ03JF8K07FFET07CIF8,hV0FFE007E00FC01FC03001F800FFC01FF8001IFJ03IFCJ07JFL07FF8S01F9IF8,hU01FFE00FC01FC03FE03801F800FFC01FFC001IFJ03IFCJ07IFEL0IFT07F9IF8,hU03FFC01F803F803FE01801F8007FC01FFC001IFJ03IFCJ0JFCL0FFCS01FF1IF8,hU07FF803F007F807FF00C00FC007FE01FFCI0IFJ07IF8I01JF8K01FFT0FFE1IF8,hU0IF007C00FF00IF00400FC007FE00FFCI0IFJ07IF8I01JFL01FES0IFC1IF8,hT01FFE00F801FE00IF806007C007FE00FFCI0IFJ07IF8I03IFEL01F8Q01JFC1IF8,hT03FFC01E003FC01FFE802007C003FE00FFCI0IFJ07IFJ03IFEL01FQ07KF83IF8,hT07FF8038007FC03FFL07C003FE00FFCI0IFJ07IFJ07IFCL03EO03MF03IF8,hT07FFL0FF807FEL03C003FE00FFCI0IFJ07IFJ07IF8L03CM07NFE03IFC,hT03FEK01FF007F8L03C003FE00FFCI0IFJ07IFJ0JF8L038K07PFC03IFC,hT03FCK07FE00FFM03C001FE00FFEI0IF8I07FFEJ0JFI018003K0RF003IFC,hT03FL0FFC01FCM03C001FE007FEI0IF8I07FFEI01IFEI03I02J0RFC003IFC,hT03EK01FFC03F8M01C001FE007FEI0IF8I0IFEI01IFEI0FM07RFI03IFC,hT018K03FF803FI0FF8001C001FE007FEI07FF8I0IFEI01IFC001EM0RFCI03IFC,iG07FF007E003FFE001C001FE007FEI07FF8I0IFCI01IF8007EL03RFJ03IFC,iG0FFE00FC00JF001CI0FF007FEI07FF8I0IFCI03IF801FCL03QF8J03IFC,i01FFC01F803JF801CI0FF007FEI07FF8I0IFCI03IF003FCL07PF8K03IFC,i07FF803F00KFC018I0FF003FEI07FF8I0IFCI03IF007F8L07OFM07IFC,i0IF007E01KFC018I0FF003FEI07FF8I0IFCI03FFE00FF8L07LFCO07IFC,hY01FFE007803KFE018I0FF003FEI07FF8I0IF8I03FFE01FF8gI07IFC,hY03FFC00F00LFE01J0FF003FEI07FF8I0IF8I07FFC01FFgJ07IFC,hY07FF801E01IF1IFL07F003FEI07FF8I0IF8I07FFC03FFgJ07IFC,hY0IF003C03F8I03FL07F003FFI07FF8I0IF8I07FFC03FEgJ07IFE,hX01FFE007807CK07L07F003FFI03FF8I0IFJ07FF803FEgJ07IFE,hX03FFC00F00ES07F001FFI03FF8I0IFJ07FF807FEg01I07IFE,hX07FF800E018S07F001FFI03FF8001IFJ07FF007FEg0EI07IFE,hX0IF0018V07F001FFI03FF8001IFJ07FF007FCY07EI07IFE,hW01FFE003W07F001FFI03FF8001IFJ07FF007FCX0FFCI07IFE,hW03FFC006K01FFCN07F001FFI03FF8001IFJ07FE007FCV01IF8I07IFE,hW07FF8M07JF8M07F001FFI03FF8001FFEJ07FE007FCS01LFJ07IFE,hW03FFM07KFCM07E001FFI03FF8001FFEJ07FE007FCQ07NFJ07IFE,hX0FEL03LFN07E001FFI01FF8001FFEJ07FC007FCO01OFEJ07JF,hX03CK03KFEO07E001FFI01FF8001FFEJ07FC007FCN01PFEJ07JF,hX018K0KF8P07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07FC003FCN0QFCJ07JF,iJ07IFCR07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07FC003FCM01IF800JFEK07JF,iI01FFCT07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07F8003FCM07FU0KF,iI03W07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07F8003FCM0FV0JF9,jG07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07F8003FEL01CV0JF9,jG07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07F8001FEL03W0JF98,iK01LFO07EI0FFI01FF8001FFEJ07F8001FEL02W0JF98,iJ07MFCN07EI0FFJ0FF8001FFCJ07F8001FFgJ0JF98,iJ07MFO07EI0FFJ0FF8001FFCJ07FI01FFgJ0JF98,iJ07LF8O07CI0FFJ0FF8001FFCJ07FJ0FEgJ0JF98,iJ03JFEQ07CI07FJ0FF8001FFCJ07FJ0FCgJ0JF88,iK0FET07CI07FJ0FF8001FFCJ07FJ0F8gJ0JF88,jG07CI07FJ0FF8001FFCJ07FJ06gK0JF8C,jG07CI07FJ0FF8001FFCJ07FgP0JF8C,jG01CI07FJ0FF8001FFCJ07FW08R0JF8C,jL07FJ0FF8001FFEJ07FT03OFL0JF84,jL0FF8I0FF8001FFEJ07FS01PFL0JF86,jL07FJ07F8I0FFEJ07ET01OFL0JF82,iO01IFCR07F8I07F8I0FFEJ07EU01NFL0IFD8,iK01MFER0FFJ07F8I0FFEJ07EW0MFL0IFD8,iK03MFER07FJ07F8I0FFEJ07EX03KFL0IF98,iK01MFER01FJ07F8I0FFEJ07Eg07IFL0IF88,iN03JFCS03J07F8I0FFEJ07EgP0IF88,iQ03FEX07F8I0FFEJ07CgP0IF88,jR07F8I0FFEJ06gQ0FF988,jR07F8I0FFEgV0FF988,jR07F8I07FEgV07F988,jS0F8I07FFgG03IF8P06F98,jX07FCg01LFEN04F98,lG01OF8K04F18,lH01NF8K04F18,iL0728004BEhO03MFCK04718,iL07LFEhP01LFCK04718,iL07LFEhQ01KFCK04718,iL07LFEhR01JFCK04F08,iL03LFEhT07FFCK04708,iL03LFEiJ0F08,iM0LFEiJ0F08,iM01KFEiJ0708,lX0708,lH03FBCR07,lI0JFCP07,lI03LFN07,lJ0NFL07,lJ01MFL07,lK03LFL07,iR07EhR07KFL03,iL01LFEhS07JF8K03,iM0LFEhT01IFL03,iM03KFEiJ03,iN0KFEiJ03,iN01JFEiJ03,iO01IFEiJ03,lX01,lI03CS01,lI01FEK038K01,lJ07MFCK01,lJ01MFCK01,iS02hQ03LFCL08,iS0FhR03KFCL08,iR0FFhS01JFM08,iP01IF,iM03LF,iM01KFE,iN07JF8,iO07FF8hY0C,lP03FC,lN03IFC,lK0MFC,lK03LFC,iS01hR01KFC,iS07hT01IFC,iR03F,iQ01FF,iN07KF,iN03KF,iO0KF,iO03JFhW018,iP03IF8hO01EJ03F8,iR03FhQ07LF8,lL0LF8,lL01KF8,lN0JF,lO03FF,,::iS078,iO0101FF8,iO01JF8,iP03IF8,iQ01FF8,lL06,lL07F,lL01FF8,lM0IF8,lM03FF8,lM01FF8,lN07F8,lN01F,lO07,,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::iI06,iI07,iI0FE,iI0FF8,iH01IF,iH01IFEi01EI01,iH03JFEhY03FFC3F8,iH03KFhY07KF8,iH07KFhY07KF8,iH07JFEhY0LF8,iH07KFJ018hS0LF8,iH07LF001FChJ0EM01LF8,iH0QFChI01FEL01LF8,iH0QFChI03JFJ01LF8,iH0QFChI07KFE003LF,:iG01QFChI0LFE003KFE,iG01QFChI0LFE003KFC,iH03FE01LFChI0LFEI07IFC,iL01LFChH01LFE,:::iL01LF8hH01LFE,iL03LF8hH01LFE,iL01LF8hH01LFC,iM0KFEhL0FFE,iN03IF,,::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::^FS

^XZ
```